# How to break Access VBA execution with an Apple keyboard

Tags: ms-access, keyboard, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

With a common Windows keyboard I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>break</kbd> to stop my routine and enter into Access VBA debug.

Now I usually work on a Mac connected with Microsoft Remote Desktop to a Windows laptop and I've got an Apple wired keyboard with numpad.

How can I stop VBA routine execution with this keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the right keys, just trying:

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F14</kbd>